# Vogel's Algorithm - Why can we read braid words from nested coherent Seifert surfaces?

Tags: algorithms, geometric-topology, knot-theory

I was reading this paper from R. Goldstein-Rose: http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2017/REUPapers/GoldsteinRose.pdf

In Figure 12 it was mentioned that if a Seifert surface is coherent and nested, then we can read off braid words from it. I did an example with the left-hand trefoil knot (see below image link) which verifies it, as the crossings in the Seifert surface reads $\sigma_{1}^3$, of which the closure is equivalent to the original trefoil knot. However I am not sure why it is always true.

[Constructing Seifert surface from a left-hand trefoil knot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV73r.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very quickly, nested coherent Seifert circles means that we are actually looking at the link as braid diagram.  Braids wrap around an *axis* which is the center of the Seifert circles.  Coherent means that the circles are oriented in the same direction, which is required for a braid closure to always "flow down." You can prove this as an exercise:

> Given a diagram $D$, $D$ is a braid if and only if all the Seifert circles of $D$ are nested and coherent.

Good luck.